# cant pass value or webview unable to load

Tags: android

i have passed value ID with a string to `Browser_activity.java` from `About_activity.java`which will direct the webview to a html file stored in assets. but when i clicked on the button it is routing to another activity but the webview is blank. i am not sure about the passing values from an activity to another but just copied from various sources.

```
package mavilla.paavaiinstitutions;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.webkit.WebSettings;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.LinearLayout;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import mavilla.paavaiinstitutions.Browser_activity;


    public class About_activity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.about_activity);





            Button button1, button2, button3,button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9;
            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);
            button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.history);
            button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ideals);
            button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.objectives);
            button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.vision);
            button6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quality);
            button7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.chairman);
            button8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.trust);
            button9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.management);


            button1.setOnClickListener(this);
            button2.setOnClickListener(this);
            button3.setOnClickListener(this);
            button4.setOnClickListener(this);
            button5.setOnClickListener(this);
            button6.setOnClickListener(this);
            button7.setOnClickListener(this);
            button8.setOnClickListener(this);
            button9.setOnClickListener(this);

        }


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_about_activity, menu);
            return true;
        }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch(v.getId()) {
                    case R.id.about:
                        // do stuff;

                        Intent a = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        a.putExtra("ID", "about");
                        startActivity(a);

                        break;
                    case R.id.history:
                        // do stuff;
                        Intent b = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        b.putExtra("ID", "history");
                        startActivity(b);


                        break;
                    case R.id.objectives:
                        // do stuff;
                        Intent c = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        c.putExtra("ID", "objectives");
                        startActivity(c);


                        break;
                    case R.id.ideals:
                        // do stuff;
                        Intent d = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        d.putExtra("ID", "ideals");
                        startActivity(d);


                        break;
                    case R.id.vision:
                        // do stuff;
                        Intent e = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        e.putExtra("ID", "vision");
                        startActivity(e);


                        break;
                    case R.id.quality:
                        Intent f = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        f.putExtra("ID", "quality");
                        startActivity(f);


                        break;
                    case R.id.chairman:
                        // do stuff;
                        Intent g = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        g.putExtra("ID", "chairman");
                        startActivity(g);


                        break;
                    case R.id.trust:
                        // do stuff;
                        Intent h = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        h.putExtra("ID", "trust");
                        startActivity(h);


                        break;
                    case R.id.management:
                        // do stuff;
                        Intent i = new Intent(About_activity.this, Browser_activity.class);
                        i.putExtra("ID", "management");
                        startActivity(i);


                        break;

                }
            }


        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Browser_activity.java

```
package mavilla.paavaiinstitutions;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;



public class Browser_activity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.browser_activity);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String string1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("ID");


        if(string1=="about"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");

        }
        if(string1=="history"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/history.html");

        }
        if(string1=="objectives"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/objectives.html");

        }
        if(string1=="ideals"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ideals.html");

        }
        if(string1=="vision"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/vision.html");

        }
        if(string1=="quality"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/quality.html");

        }
        if(string1=="chairman"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/chairman.html");

        }
        if(string1=="trust"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/trust.html");

        }
        if(string1=="management"){
            myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/management.html");

        }






    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_browser_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check after this line `WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);` if `myWebView` is not Null. If it is you should refer to `webView1`. paste the XML code here too

Comment: and by the way isn't variable `myWebView` redundant with variable `wv`?

Comment: i am really a starter and trying to do things.so sorry about that.but can you help me with the reedited code and error please.